# What's wrong with a simple equation-solving task?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

Here is my equation to solve for unknown, $c$:

```
Solve[w - 1/(w (1 - e)) == (c - 1/c), c]
```

which yields

```
{{c -> (-1 + w^2 - e w^2 - Sqrt[-4 (w - e w) (-w + e w) + (1 - w^2 + e w^2)^2])/(2 (w - e w))}, 
{c -> (-1 + w^2 - e w^2 + Sqrt[-4 (w - e w) (-w + e w) + (1 - w^2 + e w^2)^2])/(2 (w - e w))}}
```

I tried a slightly different approach to solve it by replacing the left hand side by $z$ as follows:

```
Solve[z == (c - 1/c), c]
```

which yields

```
{{c -> 1/2 (z - Sqrt[4 + z^2])}, {c -> 1/2 (z + Sqrt[4 + z^2])}}
```

And I replaced `w - 1/(w (1 - e))` back to `z` and the above solution is expressed as:

```
{{c -> 1/2 ((w - 1/(w (1 - e))) - Sqrt[4 + (w - 1/(w (1 - e)))^2])}, {c -> 1/2 ((w - 1/(w (1 - e))) + Sqrt[4 + (w - 1/(w (1 - e)))^2])}}
```

To confirm that the two approaches yield the same solution, which should be a *must*, I subtracted one from the other, expecting to get zero, but I didn't!

Here is what I did:

```
FullSimplify[(-1 + w^2 - e w^2 - Sqrt[-4 (w - e w) (-w + e w) + (1 - w^2 + e w^2)^2])/(2 (w - e w)) - 1/2 (w - 1/(w (1 - e)) - Sqrt[4 + (w - 1/(w (1 - e)))^2])]
```

which doesn't give me zero but

```
1/2 (Sqrt[4 + 2/(-1 + e) + 1/((-1 + e)^2 w^2) + w^2] + Sqrt[1 + (-1 + e) w^2 (-2 - w^2 + e (4 + w^2))]/((-1 + e) w))
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Getting answers to questions one should explain whether they are helpful or not, if not one should explain why.

Comment: @Artes, I entirely missed to do that. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all  **the system works corectly**  while **you make unjustified reductions**. Expressions `w - 1/(w (1 - e))` and `z` can be **equivalent only under certain conditions** which you simply ignore and so **you shouldn't expect that the result would be `0`**, since there are square roots involved.

`FullSimplify` as well as `Simplify` yield results which are generically true, i.e. there are exceptional cases which are not true. Instead of `FullSimplify` you should rather use `Reduce` to get always correct results and the warning below explains why the expression couldn't be simplified further.

```
 expr[e_, w_] := 
   1/2 (Sqrt[4 + 2/(-1 + e) + 1/((-1 + e)^2 w^2) + w^2] + 
   Sqrt[1 + (-1 + e) w^2 (-2 - w^2 + e (4 + w^2))]/((-1 + e) w))

 Reduce[ expr[e, w] == 0, {e, w}];
```

[image]

If we restrict only to the real domain we get a simple condition when the expression vanishes

```
cond = Reduce[ expr[e, w] == 0, {e, w}, Reals]
```

> ```
> (e < 1 && w > 0) || (e > 1 && w < 0)
> ```

and now we can exploit it as a condition in `FullSimplify`

```
FullSimplify[ expr[e, w], cond]
```

> ```
>  0
> ```

consequently we can demonstrate examples when the expression vanishes or  not

```
With[{e = 2, w = 1}, Simplify[expr[e, w]]]
```

> ```
>  2 Sqrt[2]
> ```

```
With[{e = 2, w = -1}, Simplify[expr[e, w]]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```